# Samples file not found when running snakemake using tibanna

Tags: snakemake, tibanna

I am trying to run a snakemake workflow on AWS using Tibanna. The sample list is stored in a TSV file:
`samples.tsv`.
For some reason however, this `samples.tsv` is not copied to the EC2 instance when they are created and consequently a file not found error is generated on the EC2 instance.

Does anyone have solution?

I have tried several things but without succes:

- Adding `samples: samples.tsv` to `config.yaml`
- Copying the file using `--precommand 'aws s3 cp ...'`

The only thing that seems to work maybe is to explicitly add `samples.tsv` to the `input:`  of every rule. This however seems quite cumbersome and requires to rewrite most of the rules.

Answer (score 0):

I think any shared files, samples to analyze should be available in S3 bucket for it to work.

```bash
aws s3api create-bucket --bucket $BUCKET_NAME --region $REGION --acl private
tibanna deploy_unicorn -g unicorn -b $BUCKET_NAME
tibanna add_user -u $USER -g unicorn
```

When this bucket is created you need to upload your files:

```bash
aws s3 cp yourdir/ s3://$BUCKET_NAME --recursive
aws s3 cp .secrets.yaml s3://$BUCKET_NAME/tibanna-compute/
aws s3 cp config.yaml s3://$BUCKET_NAME/tibanna-compute/
```

And then your rules in snakemake should:

```py
from snakemake.remote.S3 import RemoteProvider as S3RemoteProvider
import yaml
import os
import subprocess

S3 = S3RemoteProvider(access_key_id=config["access_key_id"], secret_access_key=config["secret_access_key"])

STEM = config["samples"]
INPUT = config["input"]
OUTPUT = config["output"]
BUCKET = config["bucket"]

rule bwa_index:
    input:
        S3.remote(f"{BUCKET}/ref/Homo_sapiens_assembly38.fasta")
    output:
        f"ref/Homo_sapiens_assembly38.fasta",
        f"ref/Homo_sapiens_assembly38.fasta.bwt",
        f"ref/Homo_sapiens_assembly38.fasta.amb",
        f"ref/Homo_sapiens_assembly38.fasta.ann",
        f"ref/Homo_sapiens_assembly38.fasta.pac",
        f"ref/Homo_sapiens_assembly38.fasta.sa",
    conda:
        "envs/bwa.yaml"
    threads: 8
    resources:
        mem_mb=8000,
        disk_mb=12000
    group: "group8Gb"
    shell:
        "mv {input} {output[0]} && bwa index {output}"
```